# Can't refresh page when sending e-mail in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have email form in my codeigniter, it is sending e-mails successfully i just cannot make it refresh page when the e-mail will be sent, if I send email and then refresh page manually it writes your e-mail has been sent successfully which is written in flashdata in my language, which means that everything is okay I just can not refresh page automatically, please help.

This is my contact Controller :

```
    class Contact extends CI_Controller {

  public function index()
  {
    $this->load->library('session');
    $this->load->library('email');
     $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
      $this->load->library('form_validation');

      $data['title'] = "Contact";

    $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
    $this->load->view('contact', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);

  }

  public function sendmail1(){
    $this->load->library('email');
     $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
      $this->load->library('form_validation');

$name = $this->input->post('contact-name');
$email = $this->input->post('contact-email');
$subject = $this->input->post('contact-subject');
$phone = $this->input->post('contact-phone');
$message = $this->input->post('contact-message');

$this->form_validation->set_rules('contact-name', 'სახელი', 'trim|required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('contact-email', 'ელ-ფოსტა', 'trim|required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('contact-phone', 'ტელეფონი', 'trim|required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('contact-subject', 'წერილის თემა', 'trim');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('contact-email', 'ელ-ფოსტა', 'trim|required|valid_email');

if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
                {

                        $this->session->set_flashdata('warmatebulia', '<h5 style="color: red;">თქვენი წერილის გაგზავნა ვერ მოხერხდა.</h5>');
                        // after storing i redirect it to the controller
                        redirect(base_url().'contact', 'refresh');
                        return FALSE;
                }
                else {

$this->email->from($email, $name);
$this->email->to('info@mymail.com');

$this->email->subject($subject);
$this->email->message('ტელეფონის ნომერი:'.$phone.'<br />'.$message);

$this->email->send();



$this->session->set_flashdata('warmatebulia', '<h5 style="color: green;">თქვენი წერილი წარმატებით გაიგზავნა, მადლობა.</h5>');
// after storing i redirect it to the controller
redirect('', 'refresh');


  }
}
}
```

This is my form on contact view page :

```
<?php echo $this->session->flashdata('warmatebulia'); ?>
                    <?php
                    $attributes = array('class' => 'form-message', 'id' => 'quote-contact-request');
                    echo form_open('contact/sendmail1', $attributes);
                     ?>

                        <div class="form-results"></div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="form-field col-md-6 form-m-bttm">
                                <input name="contact-name" type="text" placeholder="სახელი *" class="form-control required">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-field col-md-6">
                                <input name="contact-email" type="email" placeholder="ელ-ფოსტა *" class="form-control required">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="form-field col-md-6 form-m-bttm">
                                <input name="contact-phone" type="text" placeholder="ტელეფონის ნომერი*" class="form-control required">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-field col-md-6">
                                <input name="contact-service" type="text" placeholder="წერილის თემა" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="form-field col-md-12">
                                <textarea name="contact-message" placeholder="წერილი *" class="txtarea form-control required"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="გაგზავნა" class="btn solid-btn sb-h">
                    <?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

Comment: question is unclear. are you having issues redirecting after success?

Comment: `redirect('contact', 'refresh');`

Comment: If it is unclear I will explain again, In this code it should refresh page after clicking submit and page is not doing that, it is stuck when I click submit, it sends e-mail but it is stuck and not refreshing and if i refresh manually it writes what flashdata provides

Answer (score 0):

If you need to flash a success message in your contact page itself, you just redirect to index() function of your 'Contact' controller. So  please do like this

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('warmatebulia', '<h5 style="color: green;">თქვენი წერილი წარმატებით გაიგზავნა, მადლობა.</h5>');
// after storing i redirect it to the controller
redirect('contact', 'refresh');
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, I tried this and nothing happens I think that it is just not doing this redirect command on clicking submit button and can not understand why is this happening :|